# using symbol list values for dataframe name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

yes i use pandas. for example : `symbol_list = ['VETUSDT', 'TRXUSDT', 'THETAUSDT']` i want to do this: `VETUSDT=pd.read_csv("VETUSDT.csv",decimal=".") TRXUSDT=pd.read_csv("TRXUSDT.csv",decimal=".") THETAUSDT=pd.read_csv("THETAUSDT.csv",decimal=".")` i have csv files. i want to csv to pandas dataframe. but for example if symbol_list have 500 different values, can i do this with a for loop or another way? thank you

Comment: df_dict = {name: pd.read_csv(f'{name}.csv', decimal='.') for name in symbol_list} ??

Comment: thank you but it stores in a same dictionary. how can i store these different DataFrame files?

Comment: `for sym in symbol_list: globals()[sym] = pd.read_csv(f"{sym}.csv", decimal=".")`

Comment: it returns , name:sym, type str , size 9 and value : THETAUSDT .
how can i that ,it returns 3 different dataframe files?

Comment: i am so sorry your code is great. but i can't see dataframes, because uppercase excluding. now i fixed and it's work. thank you very much